# Problems with iCloud sync notifications NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification and core data

Tags: core-data, icloud

I've successfully added iCloud sync for coredata in that i can see the data being saved to the  cloud ubiquitous store.

I'm running the app on the simulator and an iphone simultaneously.  If I add or save data the store grows.  BUT,  neither app receives the NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification and therefore the data is not synced.

I've based my implementation on the Tim Roadley blog (http://timroadley.com/2012/04/03/core-data-in-icloud/) whihc was very helpful.

Any help would be muc appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the very first paragraph of Tim's article you will see this. "Note: iCloud does NOT work in the iOS Simulator. I recommend testing on two devices, such as an iPad and an iPhone at the same time."

I believe that's your answer. ;-)

EDIT:
iOS 7 now supports this

Comment: NOTE: This is no longer true for iOS 7